# How to fix payu biz integration error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, payumoney

How to fix the payu payment gateway integration hashing errors.
This is my controller codes.

```
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
    $data['tid'] = $txnid;
    $SALT = 'eCwWELxi';
    $udf1 = '';
    $udf2 = '';
    $udf3 = '';
    $udf4 = '';
    $udf5 = '';

    $hashstring = 'gtKFFx' . '|' . $txnid . '|' . '2000' . '|' . 'sdfsdgfsgsfgdfgfsgfdgsd' . '|' . 'suman' . '|' . 'suman@weborbit.in' . '|' . $udf1 . '|' . $udf2 . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $udf4 . '|' . $udf5 . '||||||||' . $SALT;

    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));
    $data['hash'] = $hash;
    $this->load->view('booking_form_view', $data);
```

And this is my form.

```
      <form method="POST" name="payuForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="gtKFFx" />
        <input type="text" name="hash" value="<?= @$hash; ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $tid; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="" size="64" />

        <tr>
            <td>Amount <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td><input name="amount" type="number" value="2000" /></td>
            <td>First Name <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="suman" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="suman@gmail.com" /></td>
            <td>Phone <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="7047752176" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Info <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td colspan="3"><textarea name="productinfo">sdfsdgfsgsfgdfgfsgfdgsd</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Success URL <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="surl" value="<?= site_url('test/success'); ?>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Failure URL <span class="mand">*</span>: </td>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="furl" value="<?= site_url('test/fail'); ?>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>

        <button type="submit" id="test"></button>
    </form>
```

When i submit the form for testing payment that giving me some hashing errors and hash not array.
[image: Hash Error]

Answer (score 0):

Before $SALT, you are using eight '|' which is not correct.

User six '|' and also amount should be float(atleast two decimals
) value eg: 2000.00

I hope this will work.

Comment: Remove udf variable if they are null. replace the hash with  $hashstring = 'gtKFFx' . '|' . $txnid . '|' . '2000' . '|' . 'sdfsdgfsgsfgdfgfsgfdgsd' . '|' . 'suman' . '|' . 'suman@weborbit.in' .||||||||||| $SALT;

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for hash parameter :

```
$hashdata = ($key."|".$txnid."|".$amount."|".$productinfo."|".$firstname."|".$email."|||||||||||".$salt);
$hash = strtolower(hash("sha512", $hashdata));
```